# How do i import a non-maven folder in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, settings

How do i import a normal folder (non-maven) alongside my maven project?

My project is a maven project (spring boot). I want to import my normal folder (full of text files, scripts and random stuff) into my project view for easy access. What i've seen online are guides on how to import other maven modules but none for non-maven directories.